# Batch/cmd: saving ping logs to a file and getting the summary paragraph afterwards

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ping

I'm trying to use ping to monitor my internet connection overnight and watch for connection dropouts, packet loss, latency spikes, and so on. I have a batch file that pings google each second and records the results to a file:

```
@echo off
    ping -t www.google.com|cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %%a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!time! !data!)&ping -n 2 localhost>nul" > ping_logs_google.txt
```

And I get output like this:

```
16:36:50.47 Pinging www.google.com [209.85.202.106] with 32 bytes of data:
16:36:51.50 Reply from 209.85.202.106: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=47
16:36:52.52 Reply from 209.85.202.106: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=47
16:36:53.54 Reply from 209.85.202.106: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=47
16:36:54.58 Reply from 209.85.202.106: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=47
16:36:55.61 Reply from 209.85.202.106: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=47
16:36:56.64 Reply from 209.85.202.106: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=47
```

.. and so on. However, when I press Ctrl-C or whatever to stop the task, I want to get the summary paragraph at the end. The one that looks like this:

```
Ping statistics for 209.85.202.106:
    Packets: Sent = 9, Received = 9, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 29ms, Maximum = 34ms, Average = 30ms
Control-C
^C
```

Now, this does work when I press Ctrl-C after running just "ping -t www.google.com" in the command window itself -- it just doesn't work when I run it from the batch file. How do I make it so that I get the summary paragraph at the end when I'm finished with the batch file?

Comment: You should have a look at [smokeping](https://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/) for this kind of task

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running continuously with **-t**, replace with "**-n 100**", where "100" is the number of times it will ping (or 1000 if you like). This will give you the summary at the end of your output file the same way it does in the command window. However, you'll want to remove any pauses, etc. and just it rip.